# Fetch Email with Mailkit order by Date - need faster way

Tags: date, sorting, memory-management, mailkit, email-client

I need to fetch emails in batches from a mail box which has been through several migrations.
There was an email provider before, then the mail box was migrated to gmail and then to O365.

When I try to use UID, the emails are not fetched in reverse date order.
like this: IMailFolderObject.Fetch(startingUID, EndUID, MessageSummaryItemsObject);
To get emails in reverse date order through Mailkit, I tried to following.

var list = IMailFolderObject.Fetch(0, -1, MessageSummaryItems.Envelope | MessageSummaryItems.UniqueId).ToList();
list.Sort(new OrderBy[] { OrderBy.Date });

The emails are fetched but it takes a real long time to complete the job. Since the mailbox is really large.

I do not want to retrieve all the emails and sort them in my program.

Is there a way to get top 50 emails (sorted by date descending since I can not guarantee the UID order is not matching the order of date descending)

and the rest in batches of 50 in subsequent calls ?

Thanks for help in advance.

This is my first question so please let me know should there be more information.

Comment: What capabilities does the server have?

Comment: You can figure out what capabilities it supports by looking at the ImapClient.Capabilities property.